# mysqli: processing a huge result set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not very strong in databases, so please forgive if the question is dump. I need to process a huge amount of data. It's natural not to load the whole data at one time. How can I retrieve rows in portions of small size (1, 10 or 100). BTW, what portion size is better?

Comment: mysqli doesn't return the whole result set. It returns one row at a time when you call `mysqli_fetch_row()` (or one of the other `mysqli_fetch_xxx()` functions.

Comment: why do you need to retrieve groups of rows? do you do some sort of batch processing? if not then fetching records by row should be just fine.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling the data out one row at a time is probably the simplest way to do things. PDO makes it very simple:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // Do stuff to process row.
}
?>
```

Comment: from the tags looks like he's using mysqli

Comment: Yes, but if the poster is asking this sort of question, he is in early stages of development at best - and even so, PDO does everything that mysqli does + more, so why not consider it?

Comment: @Fluffeh Sorry to be pedantic but `PDO` does not support everything that `mysqli` does. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly the question is not on supporting some odd features but on getting simple resultset

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh well spotted.